# SQL Start Date End Date Spread difference across months

Tags: sql, date, datediff

I currently have a database which has a start date and and end date when when a Car is being held for Maintenance. I am able to figure the difference between these dates using datediff but the problem is that the value when across multiple months is linked either to the month of the start date or the end date. I am looking to spread the difference between the months so in my analysis I can see how long the cars have been held each month in days.

Example:
StartDate: '2022-04-28 06:33:34.000'
EndDate: '2022-06-20 14:09:45.000'

Days Difference: 53 days 7 Hours 36 Minutes 11 Seconds

What I need to do is spread the 54 rounded up as
April: 3
May:  31
June: 20

I currently calculating the difference either as day percentage or in days using this logic.

```
'CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(s, STARTDATE, ENDDATE)AS float)/86400 AS DECIMAL(16,3))  AS CAR_TOTAL_DAYS_PERC' returns 53.317

 'DATEDIFF(s, STARTDATE, ENDDATE) / 86400  AS CAR_TOTAL_DAYS' returns 53
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to implement this as a stored procedure, something like GetDateSpreadString

```
    --Variables for start and end date
    DECLARE @startDate AS DATETIME 
    DECLARE @endDate AS DATETIME 
    
    SET @startDate='2022-04-28 06:33:34.000'
    SET @endDate ='2022-06-20 14:09:45.000';
    
    
    --CTE to expand the count of date numbers to be used for DATEADD 
WITH numbers
    as
    (
        Select 1 as value
        Union ALL
        Select value + 1 from numbers
        where value + 1 <= DATEDIFF( dd,@startDate, @endDate)
    ),
    --CTE to group individual days covered by spread in each of the months.
    MonthsDays AS (
        Select EOMONTH(DATEADD(d,value, @startDate)) as MonthSpread, DATEPART(dd,DATEADD(d,value, @startDate)) as DaySpread
        From numbers 
    )
    
    --USE FOR XML PATH() and STUFF() to make it a single string result
    SELECT STUFF(
        (
            Select CONCAT('   ',COUNT(daySpread),','), CONCAT( DATENAME(month,MonthSpread),',')
            FROM MonthsDays
            GROUP BY MonthSpread
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,'') AS Result
```